# Show database data with CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I just want to show my data in database with codeigniter.

My code shows `error 404 The page you requested was not found`.

**Model**

```
<?php
    class Daftar_model extends CI_Model 
    {
        public function __construct() 
        {
            //connect ke database
            $this->load->database();
        }

        public function get_pertanyaan()
        {
            $query = $this->db->get('pertanyaan_ts');
            return $query->result_array();
        }

    }
?>
```

**Controller**

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Daftar_controller extends CI_Controller {

    public function index()
    {
        //echo "Hallo";
        $this->load->model('administrator/pertanyaan/daftar_model');
        $this->load->view('administrator/pertanyaan/daftar_view',$data);
        $data["pertanyaan_ts"] = $this->daftarpertanyaan_model->get_pertanyaan;   
    }
```

**View**

```
<html>
<head>
    <title><?php echo $judul; ?></title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Daftar User</h1>
    <table border="1">
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Pertanyaan</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
            <?php
                foreach($pertanyaan as $p){
        ?>
                <tr>
            <td><?php echo $p->pertanyaan; ?></td>

        </tr>
           <?php } ?>
    </tbody>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: check your .htaccess file

Comment: have you written route ?

Comment: Daftar_controller delete `controller` name. Controller name should be Daftar. And then you can connect to *http://example.com/daftar/*

Comment: You are not passing data to your view.view should be called after this line `$data["pertanyaan_ts"]=....` and also make sure you calling the proper url because you named your controller `Daftar_controller`

Answer (score 1):

A couple changes to your controller and you should be good.

Change the name of the class and browse to this with `example.com/daftar`

```
class Daftar extends CI_Controller {

public function index()
{
    //assign the page title
    $data['judaul'] = "Daftar User";

    $this->load->model('administrator/pertanyaan/daftar_model');

    //you need to assign a value to $data before sending it to the view
    $data["pertanyaan_ts"] = $this->daftar_model->get_pertanyaan;       
    $this->load->view('administrator/pertanyaan/daftar_view', $data);
}
```

Your model returns an array so you need to access the data sent to the view with array syntax `$p['pertanyaan_ts']` not object syntax `$p->pertanyaan_ts`. The modified view file

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title><?php echo $judul; ?></title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Daftar User</h1>
    <table border="1">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Pertanyaan</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <?php
        foreach($pertanyaan_ts as $p)
        {
          ?>
          <tr>
            <td><?php echo $p['pertanyaan']; ?></td>
          </tr>
          <?php
        }
        ?>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```